# Bayes theorem where the probability of one terms is 1

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I've come across a problem where it was asked to calculate the probability $P(A | S)$ and the probabilities of each component were as $P(A) = 1$ and $P(S) = 0.538$.

How would you calculate the probability of $P(A | S)$ given that you don't know $P(S | A)$ (unless this can be derived from the given information?)

Comment: Hi, please tag as [tag:self-study]. Hint: use the law of total probability.

Comment: Thinking about concrete examples of A and S might help. If P(2+2=4)=1 and P(it is sunny in Manhattan) = 0.538, then what is P(2+2=4|it is sunny in Manhattan)?

Comment: Overkill but if $P(A)=1$ then $S$ and $A$ are independent and $P(S \mid A)=P(S)$ and $P(A \mid S)=P(A)$ if $P(S)>0$

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

Rather than focusing on calculations, think of what does $P(A) = 1$ *means*. The consequence is that $P(\neg A) = 1 - P(A) = 0$, it is constant. Think of a concrete example, like an urn containing only red balls--what could you do with the balls in the urn and how would it change the probabilities?